# XML Query with Quoted value not working

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am using XML data type for Inserting value in database.but in which XML value has a single quote(') and so that query is not executed.

```
DECLARE @resources XML
SET @resources='
<Language>
  <LocaleResource Name="admin.contentmanagement.quote.fields.quotedisplayorder">
    <Value>DisplayOrder</Value>
  </LocaleResource>

  <LocaleResource Name="custom.activitylog.addquote">
    **<Value>Added a Quote ('{0}')</Value>**
  </LocaleResource>
  </Language>
'
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **Added a Quote (''{0}'')**

i hope it works

Regards,
Vinit